# How to get first word of URL parameter

Tags: php, url

I want to echo only the first word of a url parameter. For example: /?name=Mike%20Jackson. I want only "Mike". How is that done?

I can get the whole parameter.

```
<?php // show welcome back message if coming from the waiting list email
$name = '';
if (isset($_GET["name"]))
{
$fullname = $_GET["name"];
}
?>
```

I expect the first word only.

Comment: You could [explode](http://php.net/explode) on a space and take the first index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To break the string at a space, you would use the explode function. That separates the parameter and breaks it into an array, so to get the first word you just need to get the 0th index:

```
$fullname = explode(" ", $_GET["name"])[0];
```

If space in your URL is encoded as in your example, you just need to replace the space with the encoding:

```
$fullname = explode("%20", $_GET["name"])[0];
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, the first method should be the way to go because your method of getting the parameter automatically decodes the URL.

Comment: From `urldecode()`, "*Warning
The superglobals `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` are already decoded. Using `urldecode()` on an element in `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` could have unexpected and dangerous results.*" -- from `$_GET` documentation, "*Note: The GET variables are passed through `urldecode()`.*"

Comment: @Qirel can you explain your comment? I didn't use urldecode() in my answer

Comment: "*If space in your URL is encoded as in your example*" meaning that `%20` will in fact be a space in `$_GET`.

Comment: @Qirel I understand, and that is how it should be. I was including the second method just for example purposes, but thank you for pointing out that the first method should work